# If we take a an ideal conductor and pass a constant electric field through it, what should be the ideal behavior of its free electrons?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors

When a constant electric field is passed through an ideal conductor, charge separation takes place across the given conductor. This charge separation generates an electric field of its own inside the conductor such that the net electric field intensity inside any point in the conductor becomes 0.

Here, I have two situations in my mind as to how the electrons may be behaving,

(Here, whenever the term 'electrons' is being used, I am actually referring to the free electrons inside the conductor)

**1.** **Assuming that the electric field generated due to the charge separation does not affect the charges generating the field themselves**

Here the electrons are only under the influence of the external electric field and not the 'induced' (here I'm using the single quotes as I am not aware of what term is used for the electric field generated by the charge separation) field. Now as the electrons are present on the surface of the conductor with the electric field acting normal to the surface, the electrons have nowhere to go to an thus will remain at rest.

**2.** **Assuming the electrons are themselves affected by the 'induced' electric field**

So now when equilibrium is reached, the net electric field inside any point in the conductor will be 0. This means that the electrons accumulated on one side (surface) of the conductor won't be under the influence of any electric field. In this case as well, they will remain at rest. The reason for the same being that before the net field on the electrons became 0, they were under the influence of the external field and were pushed out to the surface of the conductor. And since they were already at rest when the external field was acting on them, they will remain to do so even after the net electric field on them becomes 0.

I am aware of the fact that the electric field produced due to a point charge doesn't affect the point charge itself. Here I am a bit confused since this is a type of configuration where more than one charge is actively participating in the generation of the 'induced' field.

**I want to know which one of my assumptions is correct. Incase this whole idea is farfetched, please let me know what will be the actual behaviour of the electrons**